# It finds characters only if there is an empty line at top and bottom

Tags: php, replace

There's something really strange happening, and I'm hoping someone can figure this out for me please.

I'm using preg_match to find an exact character match in a file, yet for some reason or another, it's not finding it unless there's an empty line both at the top and at the bottom of the file.

Here is my code:

```
if ( @preg_match( "/([^0-9]{$uNumber}[^0-9])/", $numbers ) ) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not find the search term if it is the only thing in the file. For instance, if the file is `12345` and you are searching for `12345`, then it won't find it. However if the file is `x12345x` then it will find it.

What you probably want to do is allow the start and end of the file to be allowed:

```
/(?:^|\D){$uNumber}(?:\D|$)/
```